# Graphical glitch with new tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design

Aside from being ugly, there's a graphical glitch with the new tag design:

[image]

A white line down the left hand side when on a blue background.

Comment: Related to zooming, perhaps?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Nope. Not zoomed. Chrome, Mac.

Comment: I see it on Windows as well.  Both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I'm looking into it now.

Comment: @Jin While you're at it, can you [change the `line-height` to 10px](http://i.imgur.com/AcnlIEm.png)?

Comment: @fredley I'd rather not to use px for line-height when I fix this tag issue. I can adjust the top and bottom padding. I prefer to use em for everything so the tag is scalable. (that's the whole reason why I switched the old graphical tag to pure css)

Comment: @Jin No problem, I just think that they're far too 'fat' at the moment.

Comment: @Jin another thing: moderator tags are somewhat inconsistent; when they're unvisited, they show in white, but when they're visited, they're forced to render as grey because of the `!important` in `.post-tag:visited`. Could this be fixed? ([img](http://i.imgur.com/ASjlhj2.png))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pushed a fix for this, also fixed the missing bottom border on the tag when used in post body. The changes will be live after the next production build.

Comment: Much nicer, thanks!